# Missing Jenkins Job Information

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

Recently I restarted my AWS instance and got a new IP address but after I restarted both Jenkins and AWS, the information about my previous jobs was no longer shown in Jenkins.

I checked the path and it still exists in the instance but it is not shown on the web. I tried to create another project and it still created in the same path just that only the newly created project is in. Any suggestions on how to recover my missing projects??

*FYI*
I have lots of old plugins that mentions "xxx failed to load" so I do not know if that is causing it.

Comment: You can try to reload your Workspace from Disk: `Jenkins` --> `Manage Jenkins` --> `Reload Configuration from Disk`. This not only loads the configuration. It also relaods your jobs and the configuration from the jobs.

Comment: If your 'lost' job is requiring one of those plugins that are not loading, then probably its configuration is no longer valid so Jenkins is not parsing it and thus it fails to load it. You may want to create a 'dummy job' and then replace the lost config.xml with this dummy one. Then at least the job should load and you should be able to see the builds/artifacts from the previous builds. Then maybe you can rebuild the job configuration

Comment: @RNoB i tired to reload configuration from disk but the missing jobs does not appear

Comment: @IoannisK.Moutsatsos I tried to create a dummy job and replace but the dummy job disappear.I look at the log and it mention 
"com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: flow-definition"

Answer (score 1):

one of my plugins does not match and all those that depends on it will fail to show on the installed section of the plugin. Thus I remove all the plugins by deleting it directly from the plugin folder and check for the working copy that was on my previous version and download the same version of plugins. After which, all the jobs come back on screen